# Enviar y recibir archivos con curl y php

Tags: php, ubuntu, post, curl, consola

Estoy intentando enviar un archivo de X servidor a Y mediante curl, es muy importante lograr que se haga por consola y que ese archivo se obtenga en el otro archivo tal y cual se envía.

Mi problema es el siguiente, usando curl y algo de la documentación logre hacer que 2 servidores se comuniquen y puedan enviar datos entre si con el siguiente código

Por parte del servidor que envia

```
ubuntu@Xserver:~$ curl -F 'fileZip=/home/ubuntu/dumpDB/pruebas.sql' https://Y.com/transferTest/
```

Por parte del servidor que obtiene

```
<?php
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileZip'],'home/ubuntu/');
    ?>
```

Pero no puedo ni saber si el archivo si esta enviando (Aunque si me envia datos como palabras), y obviamente el archivo no almacena, el log que me pasa es

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fileZip in /git/transferTest/index.php on line 5
```

y si, aunque me diga que la variable esta indefinida, no me aparece tal error en el toro servidor, alguna idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base de este error que me saco canas, en realidad no existía en Internet una documentación completa sobre como terminar esto, así que me ha dado a la tarea de crearla.

En principio, el envió esta bien

```
curl -F 'data=/home/ubuntu/dumpDB/pruebas.sql' https://Y.com/transferTest/
```

Por ese medio enviamos el archivo, hasta ese punto estamos bien, lo que falta es el archivo que lo va a recibir, así que en el servidor Y vamos a crear un archivo php con el siguiente código.

```
<?php

    /*Directorio a guardar el archivo */
    $directorySave = "/directorySave/";

    /*se obtiene el archivo a guardar mediante la variable que enviamos por el post, en este caso data*/
    $fileSave = $directorySave . basename($_FILES["data"]["name"]);

    /*se valida que existe el archivo*/
    if (file_exists($fileSave))
    {
         /*Se elimina archi si existe*/
         unlink($fileSave);
    }

    /*Se valida tamaño del archivo*/
    if ($_FILES["data"]["size"] > 2000000)
    {
        echo "Max size of file is reached: FAIL";
    }

    /*movemos el arcvho a la ruta mencionada anteriormente, allí se va a guaradr el archivo con la exptensión que heos pedido*/
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["data"]["tmp_name"], $fileSave))
    {
        echo "SUCCESS"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "FAIL"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto tal vez no sea tu respuesta, pero quizas esto te puede ayudar
Suerte!

```
<?php
    //Archivo Entrante o remplazala
    $in_file = $_FILES["fileZip"];

    //Ruta Real del Archivo Entrante
    //tambien puedes remplazar este valor por la ruta del Archivo del Servidor X
    $temp_path = realpath($in_file["tmp_name"]);

    //Construye el archivo CURLFile
    $curl_file = new CURLFile($temp_path,'file/zip','Nombre del Archivo');

    //Genera las Variables POST para enviar la Peticion CURL
    $vars = array('fileZip' => $curl_file);

    //Enlace donde se enviara el archivo
    $end_point = "https://Y.com/transferTest/";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $end_point);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    print_r($result);
?>
```